# when I click on logout link once then it doesn't go back but when I click on logout link twice then it goes back or previous page

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, netbeans

I am doing code for logout using jsp in netbens8. My database is in mysql. I am trying to do code for logout hyperlink. I have done below code. But my problem is when I click on logout link once then it doesn't go back but  when I click on logout link twice then it goes back or previous page.

I have created one link `<a href="logout.jsp">Click here to logout</a>` in filelist.jsp page . When i click on this link then it will redircets to logout.jsp page. I want to restrict user to go back. how to do? Am I getting it wrong somewhere in code?

This is my filelist.jsp page

```html
<%-- 
    Document   : filelist
    Created on : 22 Oct, 2019, 7:48:04 PM
    Author     : Z0009289
--%>

<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="com.servlet.db.DB"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%
   
    
%>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>file_list Page</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="logout.jsp">Click here to logout</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my logout.jsp page

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
    session = request.getSession();
    
    String userid = "";
    if ((session.getAttribute("userid") == null) || (session.getAttribute("userid") == "")) {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }
    else{
        userid = session.getAttribute("userid").toString();
    }
%>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Log out Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <h2>Are you sure to logout???</h2>
        <% 
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");
            response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
            response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
        %>
        
        <a href="signout.jsp"><button type="submit">Logout</button></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my signout.jsp page

```html
  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <% 
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");
            response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
            response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
%>

      <%
    
    session = request.getSession();
    
    String uname = "";
    if ((session.getAttribute("userid") == null) || (session.getAttribute("userid") == "")) {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }
    else{
        uname = session.getAttribute("userid").toString();
    }
%>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>

        <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
          <title>Sign out Page</title>
        </head>

        <body>
          <%  
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");
        response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
        response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
        if(session.getAttribute("userid") != null){
            session.removeAttribute("userid");
            request.getSession(false);
            session.setAttribute("userid", null);
            session.invalidate();
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
            
        }
        
        %>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code snippets will works for you and will solve your error

### Logout.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
</head>
----//body tags
<%
session.invalidate();
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); 
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
%>
<jsp:forward page="index.jsp"></jsp:forward>
```

### a href

```
 <li><a href="logout.jsp">Logout</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and reply. I am confused that where should I add the above lines into my code?.

Comment: I am getting error at    <%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache"> <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">